# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have that code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    stylus = require('stylus'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

function compile(str, path){
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(stylus.middleware(
        {
            src: __dirname + '/public',
            compile: compile
        }
    ));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/multivision');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error..'));
db.once('open', function callback(){
    console.log('multivision db opened');
});

app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req, res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

var port = 3131;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
```

but when I'm trying `nodemon server.js` it throws an error:

> connection error.. { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:27017] name: 'MongoError' message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017' }

how can I improve that? I've already installed mongoose using `npm install mongoose --save` in my directory

Yeah there are dozens question like this but none of these helped me.. I'm new at nodejs and probably missing something

Comment: mongodb isn't running, or isn't running on port 27017...

Comment: Does mongodb run on the same host? The 27017 port is the default mongodb port and it seems that no mongodb is available there.

Comment: what can i do? i'm on windows

Comment: I'm going through this tutorial https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-angularjs-nodejs-apps-mean and he haven't done anything to run mongodb. only installed it and then `nodemon server.js`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515174/error-in-running-a-node-js-file

Comment: hmmm only mongod. And I was trying nodemon mongod etc. it took about 30-45 min. thanks a lot mates

Answer (score 12):

I was also facing the same issue, when I was executing `node server` on my project directory. For me the **MongoDB** service was not started, that makes this issue.

So I had to run `services.msc` and activated the service.

[image]

After that I was able to run my command.

```
D:\SVenu\MyApp>node server
Saving User
App is listening on port: 3000
Already Exist
Already Exist
Already Exist
Already Exist
Done save
```

Answer (score 11):

run **services.msc** and activate the **Mongodb** service.

Now Mongodb will connect

the status of the Mongodb  indicated as **Running**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, and found that it was a mongod issue.(I am running Ubuntu 16.04). Looking through the errors there was a directory missing. After adding the directory, I needed to change permissions, and finally, set the mongod service to start at boot.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /data/db
$ sudo chown -R $USER /data/db
$ sudo systemctl enable mongod.service
```

Comment: I was having this problem inside a custom Docker container, after adding `chown -R $USER /data/db` it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your mongodb service is probably down.
Run `sudo service mongod start` to start the daemon process

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue is old, but i came across a similar issue and the above solutions did not work for me, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

What i did to make it work was just running mongo service using this command:

```
$ mongod
```

Then everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

If you're in windows and you had this issue,
just go the installer exe app for the mongodb
and click "Repair"
this works for me

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> mongod.exe --dbpath c:\data\db

`c:\data\db` is the place where you put your db.

and when you see something like this :

```
2016-08-18T10:22:31.020+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
2016-08-18T10:22:31.022+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4356 port=27017 dbpath=c:\data\db 64-bit host=sevencai-PC0
2016-08-18T10:22:31.022+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2016-08-18T10:22:31.023+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
2016-08-18T10:22:31.023+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
```

......

and then node yourserver.js

maybe everything will be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Follow as below:

=> run services.msc and start mondodb server

and save the file in node project, you can see the server connected!!

Comment: Please don't post "have same issue" as an answer. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In Most of the case you will get the error bcz the service **MongoDB Database Server (MongoDB)** Might be stopped.

**Just start the service to be connected with DB**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's doesn't work as `localhost` but IP address works `127.0.0.1` and solves this problem:

```js
  // .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/lofydb")

    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/lofydb")
      // .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
    
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to Database");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Not Connected to Database ERROR! ", err);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. please check the MongoDB service is active and running.
   [Refer the running services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlsPZ.png)
2. If it is running and available on MongoDB compass or on MongoDB shell and if you are working with node version `>17.0.0` or so it will give error.
   So plz change to the stable version of node.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure MongdoDB is running

To run MongoDB as a macOS service, run:

> brew services start mongodb-community@5.0

And when you see:

> ==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label:
> homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu

OR type on command line, to check the mongo service.

> mongod

After run service, You can easily connect with mongdoDB localhost or remote connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it had to do with the fact that my MongoDB service wasn't running locally. Make sure you followed all the correct installation steps for whatever OS you are trying to run MongoDB service here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/install-community/

Then follow the respective guide for the running the service under "Run MongoDB Community Edition". So for example, for macOS you would do

```
brew services start mongodb-community@6.0
```

if you wanted to run as a macOS service, or

```
mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork
```

if you wanted to run manually as a background service on Apple M1 processor. The same page I shared above also has commands you can run for verifying if your MongoDB process is running.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: open conf file to edit.**

```
sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf
```

**Step 2: find port and change it.**

net: port: 27017 -> default port before any change

After changing port, my issue solved :